# Command Line Escape (Windows 7, CMD)

Tags: cmd

I am using the command line to test my serverSocket and clientSocket in Java. 
I was debugging the programs. It seems something blocked somewhere.
Well, my question is: 
How to escape the current program? 
Currently the cmd is waiting for something, how should I end the program and remain in the cmd prompt?
I tried Esc, Ctrl + ^, Ctrl + ], ] and ...almost everything I can hit on the keyboard.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: 
A quick reference for who find it useful.
[In linux]

`Ctrl + C` To terminate

`Ctrl + D` signals EOF

`Ctrl + Z` suspends a program

Comment: you will need to give a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Ctrl + c works well! May I know what is "ctrl + break"? Where is the "break" on keyboard?

Comment: On my keyboard, "Break" is on the same key as "Pause".